# Create a subset of a Java Eclipse project based on dependencies of one source file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, dependencies

I have a library Eclipse project/workspace containing functionality that is occasionally delivered to a customer.  We're all researchers so this is done very informally; I make a JAR and a Word file with documentation, and send it to them.

I prefer to send them a JAR file that only contains what they actually need, to simplify things.  If they need classes X, Y, Z and W, then I send a JAR file containing X, Y, Z, and W, as well as all of the classes that those depend on.

Right now I am doing this in a hopelessly manual way (I create a new project, drag over X, Y, Z, and W, and then drag over anything I need to fix the compiler errors).  What's the right way to automate it in Eclipse?

EDIT: Just to be clear, the Eclipse projects involved contain many more classes than are actually needed by the customer.

EDIT: Also, there is no reflection involved; I can be confident that the compiler knows what is going on.  I'm the one who wrote the code, and I avoid reflection like the plague.  The only place I used reflection is to imitate Collections.toArray(), and in that case the only class that could cause a problem is one that the user provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Byecycle, an Eclipse plugin would help, but it has been removed from Sourceforge. Not in getting a thorough automated process, but in determining the dependencies. I'm not sure whether you can get it to work on Ganymede/Galileo, since I've used this a long time back.

**Update**

The [Class Dependency Analyzer](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/) Tool might prove to be more helpful, since it comes with a plug-in extension API that *could be used* to create a plug-in to perform exactly the task that you intend to do.

**Update #2**

In case you were wondering about the usage of Ant, you can use the ClassFileSet type to obtain a class and its list of dependencies. This can be referenced inside a copy task to copy the required *class files*. Do note that this doesn't copy source files.

Internally, this method depends on the [BCEL library](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/), so if you wish to perform a copy of sources, you could attempt to write code to examine a .class file's dependencies, and copy the sources over to another directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) to automate something like this

Comment: I'm a newbie to Ant, but when I tried putting in a compile action for the specific classes involved, it ONLY compiled those and didn't pull in the dependencies.  How would this work to get the depended-on classes compiled as well?

Answer (score 2):

You are currently copying enough class files to make the *compiler* happy. However, are you sure you are copying enough class files to make the *running application* happy? Some applications load their classes via [reflection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/index.html) at run time:

```
String className = "org.my.company.Foo";
Class<?> fooClass = Class.forName(className);
Object foo = fooClass.newInstance();
```

In this example, the compiler will not complain, even if you don't copy the `org.my.company.Foo` class. However, the *running application* will most certainly complain when it can't find the class.

If you want to accommodate both situations, you can try writing a custom `ClassLoader` that records all classes being loaded by the running application:

```
public class RecordingClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private FileWriter classNameWriter;

    public RecordingClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) throws IOException {
        super(parent);
        classNameWriter = new FileWriter(System.getProperty("loaded.classes.file", "C:\\classes.txt"));
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            classNameWriter.write(name);
            classNameWriter.write("\r\n");
            classNameWriter.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not record class loading", e);
        }

        return super.loadClass(name);
    }

}
```

You could then run your application like this:

```
java
  -Djava.system.class.loader=RecordingClassLoader
  -Dloaded.classes.file=loaded_classes.txt
  YourApplication
```

The `loaded_classes.txt` file will look something like this:

```
java.lang.System
java.nio.charset.Charset
java.lang.String
...
...
YourApplication
```

You can modify the class loader to ignore any classes being loaded from the `java.` packages. After you run the application, you can then have a little program automatically copy the classes mentioned in this file.

Comment: I wrote the code involved, and I am certain that reflection is not relevant (see the question edit).  However, that would be a pretty good answer to a slightly different question. :)

Answer (score 2):

I submitted an [Eclipse enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=373863) to support such a refactoring.  In the meantime, I found some promising tools to help with the decoupling and dependency analysis.

- [eDepend](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/features/eDepend/) is a dependency viewer plugin that includes a
  Class/Package dependency diagram that displays elements dependencies,
  relationships with libraries/other projects and dependency cycles. It
  can also list find classes that caused the dependencies.
- [STAN](http://stan4j.com) structure analysis for Java
- [nWire](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/)
- [Class Dependency Analyzer](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/)
- [Dependency Finder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/)

Related questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9646912/403455)

Answer (score 1):

When you use the Export command you are given the choice to choose which files to include on the generated JAR.

Comment: If I only choose classes XYZW, will it automatically add the required classes on its own?  If I save that configuration as a ".jardesc", then will it dynamically update the output based on any changes in the dependencies of XYZW?

Comment: Unfortunately, it will not add the required classes.  You have to choose them all.

I have no knowledge about jardesc files, sorry.