# Need a tree of dependencies of all files in a project (based on imports)

Tags: dependencies, hierarchy, class-hierarchy

Even before I post this question, let me say that I found a link which possibly answers my question and here it is
[Create a subset of a Java Eclipse project based on dependencies of one source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380615/create-a-subset-of-a-java-eclipse-project-based-on-dependencies-of-one-source-fi)

So, why am I asking this question?
The last reply was in the year 2012. There could be some/more updates happened in last 3 years and so wanted to know if any of you have any updates on this.

Now comes my question
I am into a refactoring project which has many projects and classes
The whole project is built on RAD and has some projects like Online, Batch and few more as well. Totally there are 12 projects
As the first part of refactoring we are separating batch and online projects, I have to find all the dependencies of each file in the batch project on the online project and get a tree or a hierarchical structure so that I can easily analyse the impact and proceed with steps in starting the refactoring process.

Long story short, I have to get all the imports in each file of the Batch project, get its dependencies on the online project and do this recursively for all the imported files with in each of the imported java files and finally get the hierarchical strcuture.

Any help or any updates or any details will be very much appreciated.
I cannot download anything from my office and so I will be trying the details given in the above link only after reaching home today.
Also, I am using Windows7 64 bit machine and JDK7

Thanks!

Regards,
Ram

Answer (score 0):

I found few good answers within stackoverflow, though I would like to post my finding here. Let it help someone in need.
It is called VisualJArchitect.
I dont exactly remember the website or forum/community which led me to this tool
But the tool is simply awesome.
It is licensed, but they have given a time period to test it and work with it.
So, try and have your good time with it.

Website: http://www.jarchitect.com/

Thanks!

Regards,
Ram